# Могу ли я размещать хранилища для ВМ, на диске, на коротом установлен vmware ESXi?

Tags: vmware

Планирую установить гипервизор ESXi 7 на физический сервер в датацентре.
В данный момент в сервере установлены два SSD накопителя, объём которых мне понадобится для использования в установленных виртуальных машинах.
Установив гипервизор в виртуальную машину на своём компьютере я заметил, что если установлен только один накопитель, на который уже установлен гипервизор, я не могу создать на этом накопителе Datastore (для последующей установки на него гостевых ОС).
Это ограничение ESXi (и мне нужно заказать у облачного провайдера дополнительный накопитель), или я доспускаю ошибку?
*К сожалению, из-за ограничений провайдера VDS провести "эксперимент" нет возможности.*

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии ESXi 7, во время установки создаётся технический раздел ESX-OSData(VMFSL) размером 120 Гб (или менее, если диск меньшего объёма).
Что бы изменить размер, необходимо во время установки, на начальном этапе в разделе Boot options (SHIFT+O) дописать ключ **autoPartitionOSDataSize=8192** (для 8 Гб).
VMware не рекомендует делать этот раздел менее 4 Гб.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi 7.0 представил макет загрузочного носителя системного хранилища, предназначенный для обеспечения возможности добавления новых функций и возможностей в будущих выпусках. Схема разделов может занимать до 138 ГБ дискового пространства, что ограничивает доступное пространство для создания хранилища данных VMFS на небольшом сервере с ограниченными аппаратными ресурсами.

В выпуске ESXi 7.0 Update 1c добавлен параметр загрузки `systemMediaSize` для настройки пространства, используемого системным хранилищем во время установки, и лучшего соответствия назначению и размеру сервера.

Дальнейшее решение можно [найти по ссылке](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/81166).